# AC not working after disengaging the battery cables for my alarm keep blowing 5 amp fuses

Tags: ford, ac, expedition

I have a 1998 Ford Expedition. My fob for my alarm system button broke off. One day when trying to get into my vehicle, I could not get in because the button did not work for the alarm and it set off the alarm. My neighbor came to the rescue and disconnected the battery cables. I tried to start the vehicle, but I also have an alarm for the ignition which it wouldn't start.  Somehow we ended up getting it to start but now ever since then, my AC will not work. The compressor blows, but it's just hot air and it keeps blowing the 5 amp fuses for it. Any idea what this could be? They say it could be a short but I'm not quite sure what to do. One mechanic told me to unplug the compressor and see if it blows the fuse.  I don't even know how to do that! Any help would be amazing.

Comment: I'm so sorry I do apologize I did edit it and I hope anyone can help thank you so much

Comment: What fuse it blowing? Can you look at the diagram on the fuse box cover and identify it?

Comment: Which engine do you have? What did you do to get the car to start? When you say compressor do you mean the blower motor? or do you mean the compressor clutch engages?

Comment: I meant blower motor,my expedition is the little engine

Comment: The fuse that keeps blowing is a amp and it's location on diagram is #5